# Finding the composition of two piecewise functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

We seek to find $f\circ g$, with $f,g$ defined by

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 x^2&\text{if}\, x\geq 0\\
 x-2&\text{if}\, x<0 \
\end{cases}$$

$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
 x+3&\text{if}\, x\geq 4\\
 2x&\text{if}\, x<4\
\end{cases}$$

This question has thrown me for a loop. But what I came up with was:

$$f \circ g =
\begin{cases}
 (x+3)^2&\text{if}\, x\geq 1\\
 2x-2&\text{if}\, x<-2\
\end{cases}$$

Is this correct? And if not, can someone help explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(g(2))=f(2(2))=f(4)=16$ but according to your answer you have $f(g(2))=(2+3)^2=25$. So your answer is not correct.

Here is what you must start with:

$$f(g(x))=\begin{cases}(g(x))^2 & \text{ if } g(x) \geq 0\\ g(x)-2 & \text{ if } g(x) <0.\end{cases}$$

Now observe that $g(x)<0$ only when $g(x)=2x$ and $x<0$. Thus we will have

$$f(g(x))=\begin{cases}(g(x))^2 & \text{ if } g(x) \geq 0\\ 2x-2 & \text{ if } x <0.\end{cases}$$

Now consider the case when $g(x) \geq 0$. Observe that $g$ is non-negative on $[0, \infty)$ as follows:
$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
 x+3&\text{if }\, x\geq 4\\
 2x&\text{if }\, 0 \leq x<4
\end{cases}$$

Thus we will have

$$f(g(x))=\begin{cases}(x+3)^2 & \text{ if }  x \geq 4\\(2x)^2 & \text{ if }  0 \leq x<4\\ 2x-2 & \text{ if } x <0.\end{cases}$$